# Cannot run multiple karma tests using suave server

Tags: karma-runner, webix, suave

When I run the below tests individually (by commenting out) then each test passes. However, when I run all tests then I get an XmlHttpRequest uncaught exception. The suave test server receives the requests and the logging shows no errors or problems:

```
var HOME_URL = "http://localhost:3000/request";

it("should echo the test request with response", function (done) {
    var test = { act: 'test1', qry: {} };

    var promise = webix.ajax().post(HOME_URL, JSON.stringify(test));

    console.log('test1');
    promise.then(function (resp) {
        expect(resp.json().succ).to.be(true);
        done();
    }).fail(function (err) {
        done();
        throw(err);
    });

});


it("should echo the test request with response 2", function (done) {
    var test = { act: 'test2', qry: {} };

    var promise = webix.ajax().post(HOME_URL, JSON.stringify(test));

    console.log('test2');
    promise.then(function (resp) {
        expect(resp.json().succ).to.be(true);
        done();
    }).fail(function (err) {
        console.log('echo test error', app.util.inspect(promise));
        done();
        throw(err);
    });

});
```

Any ideas what the problem could be or how to debug these tests?

To run the code yourself (git node and npm have to be installed):

```
git clone http://github.com/halcwb/GenUnitApp.git
cd GenUnitApp
git checkout failingServer
scripts/run.sh
```

Open second terminal

```
./build.sh clienttests
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone running into this, you can nest the ajax calls in a before function and later on use the promises (webix.ajax returns a promise) in your tests like:

```
var HOME_URL = "http://localhost:3000/request";
var test1, test2;

before(function () {
    var req = { act: 'test1', qry: {}};

    test1 = webix.ajax().post(HOME_URL, JSON.stringify(req));
    req.act = "test2";
    test2 = webix.ajax().post(HOME_URL, JSON.stringify(req));
});

it("should echo the test request with response", function (done) {
    var promise = test1;

    promise.then(function (resp) {
        expect(resp.json().succ).to.be(true);
        done();
    }).fail(function (err) {
        done();
        throw(err);
    });

});


it("should echo the test request with response 2", function (done) {
    var promise = test2;

    promise.then(function (resp) {
        expect(resp.json().succ).to.be(true);
        done();
    }).fail(function (err) {
        done();
        throw(err);
    });

});
```